# Cypress assertions have.length;greaterThan number error

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cypress and I have written a simple test:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

describe('brand workflow', () => {
    it('List brands', () => {
        cy.login().then(() => {
            cy.visit('/brands');

            cy.listBrands().then(() => {
                // TODO: Test the table functions

                cy.get('[data-cy=data-table-row]').should('have.length', '25');
                cy.contains('[data-cy=pagination]', '50').click();

                cy.get('[data-cy=data-table-row]').should('have.length', '50');
                cy.contains('[data-cy=pagination]', 'All').click();

                cy.get('[data-cy=data-table-row]').should('have.length.greaterThan', '50');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works up to this line `cy.get('[data-cy=data-table-row]').should('have.length.greaterThan', '50');` which throws this error:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

The error message says **the argument above must be a number**, try

```
cy.get('[data-cy=data-table-row]').should('have.length.greaterThan', 50);
```

Why does a string parameter work here?

```
cy.get('[data-cy=data-table-row]').should('have.length', '25');
```

My guess is Javascript is coercing the type of the length parameter to be a string and `'25' === '25'` is true, but in the greaterThan comparison `'100' > '50'` is false.